# Creating a DOM sessionStorage item with PHP and Authenticating with javascript{SAFE}?

Tags: php, ajax, session, content-management-system

Greetings new javascript student here,

My question is as follows. 
Is it possible to create a DOM sessionStorage in a php script, also how secure would it be?
Could it be tampered with, with some javascript workarounds?

The scenario would be for a CMS(Ajax page editable region based on php User Authentication)

```
    // PHP  from User Auth Library
function setPrivileges(){

    if(USerHasAdminPersmissions){
        // <script>
        // Create a sessionStorage
        // sessionStorage.setItem('canEdit', true);
    }
}





    // javascript from init.js
if(sessionStorage.canEdit === true)
{
    // show editable regions
}
```

Pro's and Con's much apprechiated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS runs on the client browser. If your entire auth system is purely javascript-based, it'll be trivial to bypass - all the code and data are in the user's browser and it's extremely easy to fiddle with both using Firebug and similar tools.

JS-based security systems are the equivalent of using a machine workshop as a jail cell: fully stocked with grinders, bolt cutters, and other tools that can easily open the cell door.